# jpa: how to check collection parameter is null

Tags: java, jpa, hql, jpql

My requirements are:

1. Search all data if `createrIds` is null
2. Match data if `createrIds` is not null

Following code does not work, how can i fix it?

```
@Query("from CommodityEntity e where (:createrIds is null or e.createrEntity.id in :createrIds)" )
Page<CommodityEntity> searchByCreaterAndPage( @Param("createrIds") List<Long> createrIds,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Please describe the error(s) you are getting with your current code.

Comment: this is generated sql::createrIds_0_,
    :createrIds_1_,
    :createrIds_2_,
    :createrIds_3_ IS NULL 
    OR e.createrEntityId IN :createrIds_0_,
    :createrIds_1_,
    :createrIds_2_,
    :createrIds_3_

Comment: JPQL should start with "SELECT e". Also put ":createrIds" inside brackets "(:createrIds)" since some JPA implementations need that (though others don't)

Answer (score 0):

I had success with `(coalesce(:createrIds, null) is null or e.createrEntity.id in (:createrIds))` but if that works might depend on the database you use.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with db2... but `(coalesce(:createrIds, '') = '' or e.createrEntity.id in (:createrIds))` does as long as the collection isn't empty (must be null or have values)

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the query into 2 different, smaller queries, and use the `default` keyword in the interface to implement the check:

```
default Page<CommodityEntity> searchByCreaterAndPage( @Param("createrIds") List<Long> createrIds,Pageable pageable) {
    if (createrIds == null || createrIds.isEmpty()) {
        return searchAllByPage(pageable);
    } else {
        return searchByNonNullCreaterAndPage(createrIds, pageable);
    }
}

@Query("from CommodityEntity e where e.createrEntity.id in :createrIds" )
Page<CommodityEntity> searchByNonNullCreaterAndPage(@Param("createrIds") List<Long> createrIds, Pageable pageable);

@Query("from CommodityEntity e" )
Page<CommodityEntity> searchAllByPage(Pageable pageable);
```

This solutions has 2 advantages:

- 2 simple queries are likely more optimized than a complex one.
- It's database independent.

Comment: You should check for `createrIds == null || createrIds.isEmpty()`... the query would most likely blow up if an empty list is passed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with Spring but this is a solution (without pagination):

```
@NamedQuery(name="CommodityEntity.searchByCreater", query="select e from CommodityEntity e where (:createrIdsb is null or e.createrEntity.id in :createrIds)")
```

And

```
public List<CommodityEntity> searchByCreater( List<Long> createrIds) {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("CommodityEntity.searchByCreater", CommodityEntity.class)
        .setParameter("createrIdsb", createrIds == null ? null : 1)
        .setParameter("createrIds", createrIds)
        .getResultList();
}
```